# table cell background color change problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I work on another guy's code, and I try to change the table cell background color when mouse over the cell, and change back to the original background color when mouse leave. I use the following code:

```
var bgcolor=$(".cell-el").css("background-color")

$(".cell-el").hover(
       function(){
         $(this).css("background-color", "#3c3c36")}, //mouse enter, bg-color change
       function(){
         $(this).css("background-color", bgcolor) // mouse leave, bg-color change back
 })
```

Things are working fine, EXCEPT that when mouse **first time** enter the cell, the cell background color is **not** changed to "#3c3c36", but when mouse leave the cell after first entering and enter in the cell again, the cell's background color changed to "#3c3c36".

That's **the cell color never change for mouse first enter**, after that, everything is working great. What's could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: this code itself looks to be correct: http://jsbin.com/ecuro4/2/ . You may need to add more information above

Comment: changing css properties on hover?  Use the :hover pseudo-class to save yourself much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try it with simple css

```
.cell-el td:hover{
   background-color:#3c3c36;
}
```

Comment: It works in half way, what I mean is, when mouse enter, the background color changed, BUT, when mouse leave, the background color is not changed back to original color.

Comment: +1.  Use the tools what they're used for.  By the way: @Mellon, this works in my jsfiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/dQFM4/

Comment: Sorry, it works, I messed up old code with this css code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just mocked up something in jsfiddle and your code works : http://jsfiddle.net/2fadn/

Probably something wrong elsewhere.

Also, I suggest you do CSS to get this effect rather than JS. Simply using the `:hover` pseudo class should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qjnqm/

The usual problem is the line:

```
var bgcolor=$(".cell-el").css("background-color")
```

Is not in a `ready` handler.

```
$(function(){
   var bgcolor=$(".cell-el").css("background-color")
   ..// etc
});
```